# codeigniter png resize not working

Tags: codeigniter, resize, png

```
copy($image, $target);

// resize to 'md' size
$resize_config['source_image'] = $target;
$resize_config['new_image'] = $target;
$resize_config['width'] = $dimensions['width'];
$resize_config['height'] = $dimensions['height'];
$resize_config['master_dim'] = 'width';

$ci->image_lib->initialize($resize_config);

$ci->image_lib->resize();
```

It works for jpg images but not png images. For a png image it is doing the copy to the target directory then stopping when it comes to the resize

The original size is Width = 620px Height = 413px

The array for setting the new size is array ('width' => 685, 'height' => 526)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Anything from `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();`?